# Why does Python keep appending this element to list?

Tags: python, function, python-3.4

I just wrote this codes on shell;

```
>>> def foo(x=[]):
    x.append(26)
    return x

>>> foo()
[26]
>>> foo()
[26, 26]
>>> foo()
[26, 26, 26]
>>>
```

It's astonishing. I don't understand this behaviour, however, in script it's normal. Why does this appending that element when called the function? I expected that only one `[26]` each time I call the function.

Comment: It's impossible to find these duplicates when you first encounter this problem but it is such a coincidence you used the exact word *astonishing* just like the dupe

Comment: @jamylak Yea I didn't know there is a duplicate actually how can I search this question to find is there a duplicate or not lol. For _astonishing_ I just found that in dictionary English is not my main ^^